# R extract rows with a set of values in multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: r, row, extract, multiple-columns

I´ve got a dataframe with 15 columns (data are categorical).
I´d like to extract lines with contraditory categories (based in a set of rules). I tried
`Df %>% filter_at(vars(col_1,col_2), any_vars(. %in% c(8, 1)))` and it works fine for lines with category 8 or lines with category 1 ... problem is I´d like both 8 and 1 in the same line (that´s the way I figure it would catch the contraditions in the dataset).

Appreciate any ideas for this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `&` with `==`

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>%
   filter(if_any(c(col_1, col_2), ~ .x == 8) & if_any(c(col_1, col_2), ~ .x == 1))
```

-output

```
  ID col_1 col_2
1  1     1     8
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the columns and detect with a regex

```
library(stringr)
Df %>%
    filter(str_detect(str_c(col_1, col_2), "18|81"))
```

-output

```
  ID col_1 col_2
1  1     1     8
```

---

If there are more than 2 values, we may also use

```
library(purrr)
Df %>% 
  filter(map(c(1, 8), \(x) if_any(c(col_1, col_2), ~ .x == x)) %>%
    reduce(`&`))
  ID col_1 col_2
1  1     1     8
```

#### data

```
Df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, col_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1), col_2 = c(8, 8, 3, 4, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! 1st solution works just fine :) also the library(purrr) option; going to try the other options; just had to change `\(x)` to `function(x)`... I guess it´s something about my RStudio version

Comment: @Luisa It is the version of R.  In newer versions, `\(x)` works as well